# Use / not use a css class with a condition

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC project,
what I need is to have custom css classes to use one when there is a user logged in to the site, and the other when accessing the site as a guest.
I thought about using a function in the controller that checks if there is a logged in account and a ViewBag to pass a true / false value to the view.
What I ask myself is:

How do I create a condition so that taking this ViewBag with the true / false value can enable a css class and disable another?

Comment: For example you could add a class if the user is logged and apply your style with this class like `button.logged` or if the class is higher `.logged button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to apply different css using C# variable.
Assuming you have `user` and `guest` css class created, and you want to check is user logged in through `ViewBag.UserLoggedIn`:

```
@{
    var cssName = "";
    if (ViewBag.UserLoggedIn)
    {
        cssName = "user";
    }
    else
    {
        cssName = "guest";
    }
}


<div class="otherclass @cssName"> Hello </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Session` value when User gets logged in. And check for that `Session` value in View

`Controller`

```
Public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    Session["User"] = your_value;
    ...
}
```

`View`

```
@if(Session["User"] != null)
{
    <p class="your_class">User Logged In</p>
}
else
{
    <p class="your_class">Guest User</p>
}
```

Comment: This works, but in doing so I should create a copy of my page, because the css class is called from almost the whole page, not from a single button as in your example

Comment: Ok, Then above answer is good in your case.